# opencv4nodejs how to use absdiff function

Tags: node.js, opencv

Prob a silly question but I cant find out how to use the absdiff() function in opencv4nodejs. 
I have two Mats called reference and img and I want to see whats different on img from reference.

A code snippet is below

```
let reference = await cv.imreadAsync(referencePath);
const img = await cv.imreadAsync(imagePath);
// Get the difference
const diff = img.absdiff(reference);
console.log('after absdiff');
// Write out the difference
await cv.imwriteAsync(outputPath, diff);
```

My node server crashes during the function so the log never prints out. Any ideas would be great thanks .

*On a side note can someone with the rep create the opencv4nodejs tag*

Comment: As far as C++ and Python APIs' are concerned, `cv::absDiff(mat1, mat2)` takes at least 2 arguments, your first and second image respectively, how else it is supposed to calculate the diff with ?

Comment: @ZdaR ya i have it done in c++ but it seems the function in js is part of the Mat object when created. So above the img variable calls absdiff on itself which would (I presume) use itself as the first paramter against the supplied parameter

Comment: Oh my bad, It may be possible, you can look out on Github for some sample code in the projects which use opencv4nodejs and using `absdiff` method

Comment: No problem ive had a look and ive opened an issue on the github just incase it could be an implementation error. thanks for the input though!

Comment: DId you ever solve the issue? I am having same problem. The absdiff method doesnt crash if I feed the method the same images. It only crashes when the images are different.

Comment: @zEyeland check the image properties the dimensions need to be the same on both images. [Here is the github issue i created](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/issues/434) I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was ill leave this here if someone runs into the same issue!
So the images must be the same size for some reason my reference img was 2050*1520(or something like that) and my img was 1920*1080 both images must be the same size.